# Rails - Arithmetic ops on time objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, utc

Can someone explain the difference between the results of these two operations?

```
Time.now - 4.days --> 2011-08-03 18:13:33 -0400
```

and

```
Time.now.utc - 4.days --> 2011-08-03 22:13:49 UTC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time.now is returning current system time (-4hrs from UTC), Time.now.utc is converting the time to UTC time ie. GMT.